# Same values in different expandavble listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, expandablelistview

Expandable ListView Image

[image: Expandable ListView Image]

Error I am facing

[image: Error I am facing]

Same content and Image View

[image: Same content and Image View]

As u can see the above images I want to add different values to my different expandablelistview.

The problem I am facing is that it's showing me he same content in every expandable view option selected.

**MainActivity**

```
 package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer;

    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;


    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.adapter.CustomExpandableListAdapter;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.datasource.ExpandableListDataSource;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment.navigation.FragmentNavigationManager;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment.navigation.NavigationManager;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {



        String selectedOption;

        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private String mActivityTitle;
        private String[] items;

        private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
        private ExpandableListAdapter mExpandableListAdapter;
        private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
        private NavigationManager mNavigationManager;

        private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListData;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );



            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

            mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
            mNavigationManager = FragmentNavigationManager.obtain(this);

            initItems();

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
            mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

            mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
            mExpandableListTitle = new ArrayList(mExpandableListData.keySet());

            addDrawerItems();
            setupDrawer();

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                selectFirstItemAsDefault();
            }

            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }



        private void selectFirstItemAsDefault() {
            if (mNavigationManager != null) {
                String firstActionMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_1)[0];
                mNavigationManager.showFragmentAction(firstActionMovie);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(firstActionMovie);
            }
        }

        private void initItems() {

            items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choose);
        }


        private void addDrawerItems() {
            mExpandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, mExpandableListTitle, mExpandableListData);
            mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);
            mExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition).toString());
                }
            });

            mExpandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.option);
                }
            });

            mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                        .get(childPosition).toString();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(selectedItem);

                    if (items[0].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                        mNavigationManager.showFragmentAction(selectedItem);
                    } else if (items[1].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                        mNavigationManager.showFragmentComedy(selectedItem);
                    } else if (items[2].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                        mNavigationManager.showFragmentDrama(selectedItem);
                    } else if (items[3].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                        mNavigationManager.showFragmentMusical(selectedItem);
                    } else if (items[4].equals(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))) {
                        mNavigationManager.showFragmentThriller(selectedItem);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported fragment type");
                    }

                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        private void setupDrawer() {
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.option);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            };

            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }
```

**CustomExpandableListAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;



public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mExpandableListTitle;
    private Map<String, List<String>> mExpandableListDetail;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       Map<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        mContext = context;
        mExpandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        mExpandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return mExpandableListDetail.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return mExpandableListDetail.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return mExpandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mExpandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**FragmentDrama**

```
    package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.Registration;
    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment.navigation.FragmentActionListener;

    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Use the {@link FragmentDrama#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class FragmentDrama extends Fragment {

        private static final String KEY_MOVIE_TITLE = "key_title";

        String movieName;
        String movieDescription;

        public FragmentDrama() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        public static FragmentDrama newInstance(String movieTitle) {
            FragmentDrama fragmentDrama = new FragmentDrama();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE, movieTitle);
            fragmentDrama.setArguments(args);

            return fragmentDrama;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drama,container,false);

            ImageButton imageButton =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity( new Intent( getActivity(), Registration.class ) );
                }
            });

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            Drawable movieIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.webdesign, getContext().getTheme());
           // if (movieIcon != null) {
              //  movieIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            //}
            ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon)).setImageDrawable(movieIcon);

            String movieTitle = getArguments().getString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_title)).setText(movieTitle);
        }

       /* @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated( savedInstanceState );
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                 movieName = savedInstanceState.getString("selectedMovie",movieName);
                movieDescription = getString(getStringId(movieName));
            }else {
                Bundle bundle = getArguments();
                movieName = bundle.getString( FragmentActionListener.KEY_SELECTED_MOVIE,"Website Design");
                movieDescription = getString(getStringId(movieName));
            }

        }

        private int getStringId(String movieName){
            if(movieName.equals("Website Design")){
                return R.string.Website_Design;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Web Application")){

                return R.string.Web_Application;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Graphic Design")){
                return R.string.Graphic_Design;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Website Redisigning")){
                return R.string.Website_Redisigning;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Software Development")){
                return R.string.Software_Development;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Apps Development")){
                return R.string.Apps_Development;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Digital Marketing")){
                return R.string.Digital_Marketing;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Domain Registration")) {
                return R.string.Domain_Registration;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Server Hosting")) {
                return R.string.Server_Hosting;
            }else if(movieName.equals("Web Security(SSL)")){
                        return R.string.Web_Security;
            }else {
                return R.string.Website_Design;
            }
        }*/
    }

#drama_fragment.xml

    [<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  tools:context="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment.FragmentDrama">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/movie_icon_container_height">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/movie_icon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/query"
                android:src="@drawable/webdesign" />

            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding_default"-->
                <!--android:text="@string/services"-->
                <!--android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@color/white"/>-->

        </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/layout_padding_default"
            android:text="@string/content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="adsjxknxlanm,a"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      @Override
            public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


                String movieTitle = getArguments().getString(KEY_MOVIE_TITLE);
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_title)).setText(movieTitle);

 String imagekey = getArguments().getString(KEY_FOR_IMAGE);
 String content= getArguments().getString(KEY_CONTENT);

if (imagekey = "movie"){
  Drawable movieIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.webdesign, getContext().getTheme());
               // if (movieIcon != null) {
                  //  movieIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                //}
                ((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_icon)).setImageDrawable(movieIcon);

}else if(){
so on . . . 
}

 ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content)).setText(content);

            }



in fragemt you are only changing title ;

and image is same and not setting content .

pass content and imagekey to choose which image to show along with title
```

Comment: sir I want to change every single thing on every expandable menu

Comment: yes ,you are using same image in imageview  , movie title is different   using getargument  and settext for content needs to be put

Comment: sir can you help me with that how to do that